# using path with "*" in unzip command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got several zip files and I want to unzip, in other path, only the files which have some characteristics, so I execute this command in linux:

```
unzip -q -o ./path1/*/"*.zip" Key/* -d /path2/
```

But this execution returns me the following:

```
unzip:  cannot find or open ./path1/*/*.zip, ./path1/*/*.zip.zip or
./path1/*/*.zip.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
```

If I execute this other opcion:

```
unzip -q -o ./path1/*/*.zip Key/* -d /path2/
```

It just unzip what it's included into the first zip in the /path1/*/, and returns the next message:

```
caution: filename not matched:  ./path1/folder/zipFileName1.zip
caution: filename not matched:  ./path1/folder/zipFileName2.zip
caution: filename not matched:  ./path1/folder/zipFileName3.zip
caution: filename not matched:  ./path1/folder/zipFileName4.zip
```

I need to use an `"*"`, or something similar into the path, because I don't know the name of one folder.

Could somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: The first option looks for a file named literally `*.zip`; I don't believe that you have such a file. The second option work as it should; `unzip` accepts exactly *one* archive name: if you want to unzip multiple archives you must loop through their names and feed them one by one to `unzip`.

Comment: The problem cames, when using *, inside the path, if you don't use *, the command works correctly, and unzips multiple archives without using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `for`, loop:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in path1/*.zip path2/*/*.zip ; do [ -r "$f" ] && unzip -l "$f" ; done
```

or

```
shopt -s nullglob                   # see comments 
for f in path1/*.zip path2/*/*.zip  # all source paths go in here
do 
  [ -r "$f" ] && unzip -l "$f"      # + whatever parameters you need for unzip
done
```

Comment: I edited slightly to filter out non-existent names; for example, suppose there is a subdirectory named `subdir` which does not contain any Zip file: in this case, `*/*.zip` will include (possibly among others) the non-existent name `subdir/*.zip`.

Comment: @AlexP Your example wouldn't happen; if there are no zip files in in `path2/subdir1` but there are some in `path2/subdir2`, then the expansion of `path2/*/*.zip` won't include `path2/subdir1/*.zip`. Your test is still needed, though, in case `path2/*/*.zip` fails to match *any* files, in which case it remains unexpanded (by default; you can use `shopt -s nullglob` to make unmatched patterns disappear instead).

Comment: Thank you! I apply a similar solution: _for item in `find ./path1/ -type f -name "*.zip"` ; do unzip -q -o $item Key/* -d ./path2 ; done_

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` for looking up `zip` files and `unzip` them one by one:

```
find ./path1 Key -type f -name "*.zip" -exec unzip -q -o -d /path2 {}
```

Note that this will unzip all `zip` files from all subdirectories of `path1` and `Key`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've use your idea of using the find command and I've tried this: _for item in find ./path1/ -type f -name "*.zip" ; do unzip -q -o $item Key/* -d ./path2 ; done_